# Basic Math: Simplifying $w=z^2+3z$

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is:
Consider the transformation
$$w=z^2+3z$$
from the $z$-plane where $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$.

Determine the image of the line $y=1$ and $x=3$ in the $w$-plane

My attempt at a solution:
$$\begin{align}
u+iv=w&=z^2+3z\\
&=(x+iy)^2+3(x+iy)\\
&=x^2+ixy+ixy+(iy)^2+3x+3iy\\
&=x^2+2ixy-y+3x+3iy\\
&=x^2+3x-y+i(2xy+3y)
\end{align}$$
So
$$\begin{align}
&u=x^2+3x-y\\
&v=2xy+3y
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
w&=z^2+3z\\
z^2+3z-w&=0\\\text(Which is a Quadratic euation)\\\\
x+iy=z&=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-4w}}{2}\\
&=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-4(u+iv)}}{2}
\end{align}$$
So how do I now break $u$ and $iv$ appart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation $$
w=z^2+3z
$$
is a quadratic equation w.r.t. $z:$
$$z^2+3z-w=0 \\
z_{1,2}=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-4w}}{2}
$$
 Image of the line $\gamma_1=\{z=x+iy:\quad y=1\}$ can be obtained by substitution $y=1$ in
$$\begin{align}
&u=x^2+3x-y\vert_{y=1}=x^2+3x-1\\
&v=2xy+3y\vert_{y=1}=2x+3 \; \Rightarrow \;x=\frac{v-3}{2}
\end{align}$$ hence
$$u=\left(\frac{v-3}{2}\right)^2+3\cdot\frac{v-3}{2}-1 \, .$$
Analogously, image of another line $\gamma_2=\{z=x+iy:\quad x=3\}$ 
\begin{align}
&u=x^2+3x-y\vert_{x=3}=18-y \; \Rightarrow \;y=18-u \\
&v=2xy+3y\vert_{x=3}=6y+3y=9y \; \Rightarrow \;v=9(18-u)=-9u+162
\end{align}
hence
$$v=-9u+162$$

Comment: Why substitute $y=1$ and not $x=3$?